# Below function does not work as desired

Tags: c, string

I need to write a function which takes 2 words and count its length. I wrote below one but this code only woks for 1st word. How can I improve it to count whole sentence?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int findlen(int *s);

int main(void)
{

  char string1[80];
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  scanf("%s", string1);

  printf("Lenght of %s is %d\n", string1, findlen(string1));

}

//find the length of the inputted string
int findlen(char *s)
{

  int count = 0;
  while (*s != '\0')
  {
    s++;
    count++;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: Since you're only performing a single `scanf()` with a single `%s` argument, you're only getting a single string.

Comment: Generally avoid using `scanf()`. I haven't yet seen any good reason for using it. `fgets()` and sometimes `fgetc()` are appropriate and they **actually do** what you think they do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scanf` will take the one word input only.. (i.e) it breaks when space appears..

Try `fgets` to read the complete string till `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets` to safely get the line from your file:

[From here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

so replace your scanf line with:

```
fgets(string1, sizeof(string1), stdin);
```

If you used `gets` instead, it doesn't know how large your buffer is and it would crash when reading too large line.

Next, if you want to know a length of your string you could use [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) function from `string.h`:

```
#include<string.h>
...
printf("Lenght of %s is %d\n", string1, strlen(string1));
```

Answer (score 0):

use [%^\n] format specifier so that it will scan the string till '\n' encounter so the problem in scanning string having space(eg. "hello   word") will be solved.

```
scanf("[%^\n]",straddr);
```